# What does the number below the norm means?

Tags: matrices

When I was reading an essay, I came across a notation which I do not know its meaning.

Let $M=U^*\Sigma^*(V^*)^T$ be its SVD. Let $u_i^{*,T}, i\in[n]$, be the $i$-th row of $U^*$ and $v_j^{*,T}, j\in[n]$, be the $j$-th row of $V^*$. Now we present the incoherence assumptions on $M$.

There exists a constant $\mu_0\geq1$ such that
$$\lVert u_i^*\rVert_2^2\leq\frac{\mu_0k}{n},\forall i\in[n]\text{ and }\lVert v_j^*\rVert_2^2\leq\frac{\mu_0k}{n},\forall j\in[n]$$

What does the number 2 below the norm means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 refers to the $\ell_2$-norm, which is the conventional Euclidean norm that we typically think of. Look at [this article on Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html).